# How to change chart colors in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to change the colors of a pie chart in VBA. I 'managed' to change the font color, which is not what I wanted, this way:

```
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(1).Border.ColorIndex = 6
```

I want to change the color of the actual piece of pie.
I also have to set specific colors, which are part of the standard palette. The 6 above gives me a flashy yellow but I want the colors highlighted here

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this is for Excel 2007?  (The coloring system for versions <= 2003 is different from the one used in 2007.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When faced with problems like this, I usually record a macro and examine what Excel does. I'd try this:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

For colors, check out the `RGB(red,green,blue)` function.

Comment: Great ! Changed ColorIndex to Color to be able to use RGB() :
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)

Comment: recording may not work in Excel 2007. If I remember correctly, recording chart changes resulted in nothing being recorded. (Happy to be corrected :) )

Comment: No @guitarthrower you are actually correct. The charting engine changed in Excel 2007 and recorder support was not re-added.